# How do I use a search bar with a tableview that is populated with a plist?

Tags: uitableview, search, xcode5, plist, searchbar

I have seen many examples and tried many different ways of doing this. I have a plist with a lot of data in it and need to be able to use a search bar on it in the tableview. I want to be able to have a subtitle view in the tableViewCell but only search the main text label. Is this possible? Is it better to use Core Data?

Thank you!